# Is it normal for a journal submission to show "awaiting assignment" for more than a month?

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper more than one month ago. The status of my submission is still "awaiting assignment". May I ask if this is normal? How long have I to wait before formally asking the editor about the status of my submission? My field is mathematics.

Comment: It's a little unusual (but not uncommon). Sometimes it takes time to find a referee.  It also depends on how busy your editor is.  I would wait a few more weeks before enquiring with the journal.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of something. Maybe http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18543/article-awaiting-reviewer-invitation-6-months-after-submission?rq=1 or http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16624/with-editor-status-for-2-months-is-it-normal?rq=1 or http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24162/is-it-okay-to-inquire-about-the-status-of-a-paper-when-the-online-submission-sys/24171#24171

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the journal. Have you been contacted by the editor upon receipt of your paper? If not, I would contact them immediately just to check up. A month is a long time to go with no word. My paper submissions (all to the Astrophysical Journal) have all been followed up by the editor within a week of initial submission.

Comment: There is an acknowledgement of receipt of my submission. However, I think it is computer generated. I did not received any follow-up email from the the editor.

Comment: Then it can't hurt to send them an email inquiring.