# What are the reasons that keep manuscript status as 'manuscript submitted' over five months?

Tags: peer-review, journals, paper-submission, editors, rejection

I submitted a manuscript to a journal five months ago. And the status has remained 'manuscript submitted' since then. I wrote two letters to politely ask EIC about my manuscript but there's no response. I'm quite worried about the situation here because I don't know if it is worth withdrawing it right now. Could you please share some of your views about what kind of reseasons can cause such delay? I know pretty well about how journal flow works, but five months with unassigned status, that's frustrating.

Thank you!

Comment: You've structured this as a "workflow" question, hence a duplicate. But you could send the EIC a note that you will withdraw your paper on (future date certain) unless they respond to your enquiry.

Comment: [This answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/16625/17254) offers some possible reasons for a delay of 2 months. Also related questions: [Is it okay to inquire about the status of a paper when the online submission system shows no update three months after submission?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/24162/17254), [Article awaiting reviewer invitation 6 months after submission](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18543/17254).

Comment: By far the most common reason for this is that the editors are inactive, so yeah: ask for a status update.